# Docker - Файл есть (ls) но его нет. Как исправить? Почему так?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Вот такой скрипт - ENTRYPOINT в докер файле

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /venv/bin -lah
ls /venv/bin/python -lah
ls /venv/bin/python3 -lah
/venv/bin/python -V
/venv/bin/python manage.py migrate
/venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Причем вывод следущий

```
total 156K
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875178444Z drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Aug  7 18:46 .
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875181260Z drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Aug  7 18:46 ..
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875183624Z -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.9K Aug  7 17:58 Activate.ps1
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875185668Z drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Aug  7 18:46 __pycache__
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875187592Z -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Aug  7 17:58 activate
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875189515Z -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  898 Aug  7 17:58 activate.csh
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875191419Z -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Aug  7 17:58 activate.fish
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875193342Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  218 Aug  7 18:46 automat-visualize
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875195286Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  215 Aug  7 18:46 celery
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875197170Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  224 Aug  7 18:46 cftp
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875199073Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 18:45 chardetect
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875200977Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  227 Aug  7 18:46 ckeygen
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875202850Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  225 Aug  7 18:46 conch
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875204744Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  213 Aug  7 18:45 distro
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875206627Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  264 Aug  7 18:46 django-admin
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875208531Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  654 Aug  7 18:46 django-admin.py
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875210445Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  251 Aug  7 18:46 faker
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875212318Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  218 Aug  7 18:02 gunicorn
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875214202Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7K Aug  7 18:45 jp.py
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875216085Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  227 Aug  7 18:46 mailmail
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875217959Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  211 Aug  7 18:45 netaddr
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875219832Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  245 Aug  7 18:45 normalizer
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875221726Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 17:58 pip
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875223609Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 17:58 pip3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875225513Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 17:58 pip3.10
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875227397Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 17:58 pip3.11
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875229280Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 18:46 py.test
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875231174Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 18:46 pyhtmlizer
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875233057Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  222 Aug  7 18:46 pytest
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875234941Z lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Aug  7 17:58 python -> python3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875237115Z lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Aug  7 17:58 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875239179Z lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Aug  7 17:58 python3.10 -> python3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875242164Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  220 Aug  7 18:46 scrapy
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875245000Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  217 Aug  7 18:45 sqlformat
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875251121Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  227 Aug  7 18:46 tkconch
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875253105Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  214 Aug  7 18:46 tldextract
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875255009Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  219 Aug  7 18:46 trial
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875256892Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  239 Aug  7 18:46 twist
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875258796Z -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  220 Aug  7 18:46 twistd
2023-08-07T19:08:16.875870648Z lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug  7 17:58 /venv/bin/python -> python3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.876523819Z lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug  7 17:58 /venv/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
2023-08-07T19:08:16.876807123Z ./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 5: /venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
2023-08-07T19:08:16.877094885Z ./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 6: /venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
2023-08-07T19:08:16.877353893Z ./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 7: /venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Какая то непонятная хрень

---

Сам питон устанавливается

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get -y install bash
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip python3-venv python3-dev python3-setuptools
RUN apt-get -y install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev libopenjp2-7-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python3-tk \
    libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libxcb1-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev

RUN python3 --version

RUN python3 -m venv /venv

...



ADD docker/development/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN cat docker-entrypoint.sh
# ADD docker/development/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh ./docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

#RUN ls /usr/bin/python*
#CMD sh
#ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-e", "./docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

---

```
python3: /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3
2023-08-07T20:21:47.773728494Z ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/python*': No such file or directory
2023-08-07T20:21:47.775139503Z ./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 4: /venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
2023-08-07T20:21:47.775411994Z ./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 5: /venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

```
                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [ 9/20] RUN ln -s /etc/python3 /usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                            0.3s
------
 > [ 9/20] RUN ln -s /etc/python3 /usr/bin/python3:
#0 0.230 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists
------
Dockerfile:18
```

Comment: Интересно, но почему то там нет. Спасибо. Постараюсь покопать в эту сторону. Но странно что `python3 -m` создал неверную ссылку

Comment: То есть `python3` есть, а `/usr/bin/python3` нету? Какая-то магия. Что пишет `which python3` и какой это дистрибутив вообще?

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:22.10`.

`which python3` - пусто

Comment: Ну странно, тогда `RUN python3` тоже должны не работать

Comment: Мне остаётся только предположить, что внутри `...` вы творите какую-то дичь, которая удаляет его. Видимо, нужен [mcve] таки?

Comment: так `RUN python3` работал, не работает ни `CMD` ни `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: кажется я понял причину. между контейнером постгресс и этим поставил общую папку /usr/bin/... потому что psycopg2 требовал исполняемый файл из постгресс

Comment: `CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path.`.

Comment: Вы зачем-то пытаетесь запускать `dbshell` в контейнере, что ли?

Comment: Да. Проверяю что все работает

Comment: Вот поэтому и не работает, перестаньте запускать dbshell и всё будет работать 

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Учту на будущее. Пойду разбираться как прокинуть редис теперь